# ChiSqSelector - Real Features - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am building a NB model with Spark 1.6 and using ChiSqSelector to identify the top features. I have a total of 7 features and looking for the top 3. While the process runs fine, how will i identify the actual feature that has been rated as the top feature. Since the data is categorized, i am not able to map the output to the actual input column.

```
val chidata = cat_recs.map(r => (r.getDouble(targetInd), Vectors.dense(featuresidx.map(r.getDouble(_)).toArray))).toDF("target","features")
val sel = new ChiSqSelector().setNumTopFeatures(3).setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("target").setOutputCol("selectedFeatuers")
val chiresult = sel.fit(chidata).transform(chidata)
```

The output is

```
scala> chiresult.foreach(println)
[1.0,[0.0,2.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,1.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]]
[1.0,[4.0,3.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,1.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]]
[0.0,[3.0,2.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,3.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]]
[1.0,[1.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,7.0,5.0,2.0],[0.0,1.0,7.0]]
[1.0,[0.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,7.0,5.0,3.0],[0.0,1.0,7.0]]
```

Structure -- target: double, features: vector, selectedFeatures: vector
From the above, lets take the example of the first row

```
[1.0,[0.0,2.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,1.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]]
```

how can i identify which 0.0 it is referring to in the selectedFeatures, similarly in 5th row as well.

Please help..

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example:

```
[1.0,[0.0,2.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,1.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]]
```

the last column `[0.0,5.0,7.0]` represents the values of selected features, in this case features 2, 3 and 4 (counting from 0). To extract future indices just use

```
val model = sel.fit(chidata)
val importantFeatures = model.selectedFeatures
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that i can get the selectedFeatures, but my question was, how will i know that 0.0 in the selectedFeatures was the 0th indice and not the 2nd.

    [1.0,[0.0,2.0,0.0,5.0,7.0,5.0,1.0],[0.0,5.0,7.0]] 

    selectedFeatures(0) = 0.0
    selectedFeatures(1) = 5.0
    selectedFeatures(2) = 7.0

in the data we have two 0.0 and how can we say that selectedFeatures(0) is the first 0.0 and not the subsequent 0.0

Thank you

Comment: 'selectedFeatures' returns 'Array[Int]' with indexes, not values, so in your case this should return (2, 3, 4) which means that selected features are 3rd, 4th and 5th columns.

Comment: thanks for your response.

**Unfortunately when i do the following 
scala> chiresult.select("selectedFeatures").show
+----------------+
|selectedFeatures|
+----------------+
|   [2.0,1.0,7.0]|
|   [0.0,1.0,7.0]|
|   [0.0,1.0,7.0]|

i seem to get the values and not an Array[Int] **

Comment: Do not select column, it's a method in the model, use model.selectedFeatures exactly as it is in my answer

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, please select it as the answer :-)