# How to check selected features with PySpark's ChiSqSelector?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, feature-selection

I'm using PySpark's ChiSqSelector to select the most important features. The code is running well, however I can't verify what my features are in terms of index or name.

**So my question is: How can I identify what the values ​​in selectedFeatures are referring to?**

I have the sample code below that I use only four columns for the purpose of facilitating the visualization, however, I have to do this for a DF with almost 100 columns.

```
df=df.select("IsBeta","AVProductStatesIdentifier","IsProtected","Firewall","HasDetections")


from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["IsBeta","AVProductStatesIdentifier","IsProtected","Firewall"], outputCol="features")
vec_df = vec_assembler.transform(df)

selector = ChiSqSelector(featuresCol='features', fpr=0.05, outputCol="selectedFeatures",labelCol= "HasDetections")
result = selector.fit(vec_df).transform(vec_df)
print(result.show())
```

[image]

And yet, when trying to apply the solution I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606505/chisqselector-real-features-spark). I still cannot understand which columns are selected in terms of name or index. That is, which are the features that are being selected.

```
model = selector.fit(vec_df)
model.selectedFeatures
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your features. Why are features like `IsBeta` not just a flag but a tuple consisting of integer and lists?

Comment: It is because I did OneHotEncoder for this feature. But you a right, once  it wasn't even necessary, @pythonic833.  However, even so, I believe that this would not facilitate access to the name and indexes of the most important features

Comment: Actually the `model.selectedFeatures` usually gives the indices of the most important features. I can post an example as answer if that helps you

Comment: @pythonic833, this would help a lot. If you can share this example, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Please don't use one hot encoded features, the ChiSqSelector should be directly used on categorical (non-encoded) columns, as you can see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector.html).
Without the one-hot encoded stuff the selector usage is straight forward:

Now let's look at how the ChiSqSelector is used and how to find the relevant features by name.
For example usage I'll create a df with only 2 relevant columns (AVProductStatesIdentifier and Firewall), the other 2 (IsBeta and IsProtected) will be constant:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create df
df_p = pd.DataFrame([np.ones(1000, dtype=int),
             np.ones(1000, dtype=int),
             np.random.randint(0,500, 1000, dtype=int),
             np.random.randint(0,2, 1000, dtype=int)
             ], index=['IsBeta', 'IsProtected', 'Firewall', 'HasDetections']).T
df_p['AVProductStatesIdentifier'] = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1000)

schema=StructType([StructField("IsBeta",IntegerType(),True),
                   StructField("AVProductStatesIdentifier",StringType(),True),
            StructField("IsProtected",IntegerType(),True),
            StructField("Firewall",IntegerType(),True),
            StructField("HasDetections",IntegerType(),True),
            ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    df_p[['IsBeta', 'AVProductStatesIdentifier', 'IsProtected', 'Firewall', 'HasDetections']],
    schema
)
```

First let's make the column `AVProductStatesIdentifier` categorical

```
mapping = {l.AVProductStatesIdentifier:i for i,l in enumerate(df.select('AVProductStatesIdentifier').distinct().collect())}

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])

df = df.withColumn("AVProductStatesIdentifier", mapping_expr.getItem(col("AVProductStatesIdentifier")))
```

Now, let's assemble that and select the 2 most important columns

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["IsBeta","AVProductStatesIdentifier","IsProtected","Firewall"], outputCol="features")
vec_df = vec_assembler.transform(df)

selector = ChiSqSelector(numTopFeatures=2,featuresCol='features', fpr=0.05, outputCol="selectedFeatures",labelCol= "HasDetections")
model = selector.fit(vec_df)
```

Now execute:

```
np.array(df.columns)[model.selectedFeatures]
```

which results in

```
array(['AVProductStatesIdentifier', 'Firewall'], dtype='<U25')
```

The two non-constant columns.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question, and if one of my variables is a string, any recommendations on how to handle this situation? @pythonic833

Comment: @Tazz: I've updated my answer to the case when you have a string column. The trick is to make it categorical before applying the selector